# Reference to an object inside an array in another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

Following is the `WorkingDay` model

```
const workingDaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    availableSlots: [
        {
            startTime: Date,
            endTime: Date,
            size: Number,
            enrolledUsers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Response' }]
        }
    ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('WorkingDay', workingDaySchema);
```

And the following is the `Response` model:

```
const responseSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: { type: String },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    age: { type: String },
    gender: { type: String },
    height: { type: String },
    weight: { type: String },
    food: { type: String },
    phone: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    category: { type: Array },
    answers: { type: Object },
    assignedSlot: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: availableSlots, default: null }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


module.exports = mongoose.model("Response", responseSchema);
```

Every object inside the `availableSlots` array has it own unique _id.[image: WorkingDay document sample]

How to create a reference to an object inside `availableSlots` from the `assignedSlot` field of `response`? Also how to populate the same?

I tried referencing the availableSlots objects using

```
assignedSlot: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: availableSlots, default: null }
```

and

```
assignedSlot: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "WorkingDay.availableSlots", default: null }
```

but it did not work.

Comment: hi, have you find this solution. Currently stuck in this type of problem.

Comment: No, I just changes the schema to make a separate collection of `availableSlots`.

Answer (score -1):

```
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema.Types;

assignedSlot: [{ type: ObjectId ,ref:"WorkingDay"}]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.